# Bitstream lexer generator

Tags: bit-manipulation, flex-lexer, lexical-analysis, bitstream

I have a number of packet formats that are bit-oriented. Rather than writing many fairly complex lexer by hand I am looking for a bit-level lexer generator, a bit-oriented version of flex/lex say. Obviously I could just write straight **C**, but I was wondering whether such a bit-level lexer generator exists. After a quick Google, I found a number of media decoders and such, however, I am not parsing media files, but network packets.

Alternatively is there a way to run flex in a bit-oriented made?

Answer (score 1):

You could look into redefining `YY_INPUT` (see *Generated Scanner* in the `flex` documentation) and decompose each input byte into its individual bits and use `'0'` and `'1'` as alphabet of the regular expressions. You may want to consider if a slightly bigger alphabet can be defined with a simple definition of `YY_INPUT`.